# copying a file to the server using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I cannot believe this is so difficult. If using nodejs and standard html, I can transfer a file by doing:

index.html:

```
<form id       =  "uploadForm"
     enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
     action    =  "/api/photo"
     method    =  "post"
>
<input type="file" name="userPhoto" />
<input type="text" placeholder="keywords" name="keywords" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

and on the server.js

```
var express=require("express");
var multer  = require('multer');
var app=express();
var done=false;


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/')); 

/*Configure the multer.*/
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads/',
 rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename+Date.now();
  },
onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
  console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...')
},
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
  console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path)
  done=true;
}
}));


/*Handling routes.*/
app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendfile("index.html");
});

app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
  if(done==true){
    res.end("File uploaded.");
  }
});

/*Run the server.*/
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

By doing that, any picture I load gets copied in the uploads folder. Now, I want to use angular for different reasons. As it turns out, I need a directive. Why, I don't understand (but that's [another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/283109/why-sending-a-file-is-so-difficult-using-angular)). Since I'm using multer, I need the data to be of type "multipart/form-data". This is my index.html:

```
</<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="formExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form ng-submit="examplePost()" role="form" >
        <input type="file" bind-file="" ng-model="file" />
        <input type="text" ng-model="keywords" placeholder="keywords"/>
        <input type="submit" ng-onclick="submit" value="Upload Image" >
    </form>

</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
        $scope.master = {};

        $scope.examplePost = function() {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/upload-file',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: {
                upload: $scope.file
            },
            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    formData.append(key, value);
                });

                return formData;
            }
        })
        .success(function (data) {

        })
        .error(function (data, status) {

        });

        };


    }])
    .directive('bindFile', [function () {
        return {
            require: "ngModel",
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
                el.bind('change', function (event) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(event.target.files[0]);
                    $scope.$apply();
                });

                $scope.$watch(function () {
                    return ngModel.$viewValue;
                }, function (value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        el.val("");
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and I get a beautiful 500 response: Error: Multipart: Boundary not found.
Now, I don't want to use any more external modules. I could, but the truth is that I have to write a lot of code and send many files plus some data, so I want to fully understand what's going on before choosing an external module (or writing it).

How do I solve the error 'Boundary not found' and what does it means?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning what is "boundary", wikipedia pretty much explains it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

> A MIME multipart message contains a boundary in the "Content-Type: "
>   header; this boundary, which must not occur in any of the parts, is
>   placed between the parts, and at the beginning and end of the body of
>   the message, as follows:
>
> ```
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=frontier
>
> This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
> --frontier
> Content-Type: text/plain
>
> This is the body of the message.
> --frontier
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> PGh0bWw+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgPC9oZWFkPgogIDxib2R5PgogICAgPHA+VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUg
> Ym9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZS48L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==
> --frontier--
> ```

Comment: To build on this answer: given the way that, in the OP's code, the `Content-Type` header is removed, it is likely that the declared boundary is also removed (and the boundary is not declared in the `headers` object either). The OP should look at the HTTP headers sent to see what is happening. (Should be easy with the devtools)

Comment: I took out the Content-Type declaration removal. Same problem.

Comment: @cauchy: Then look at the HTTP headers (e.g. Open the "Network" tab in Chrome developer tools, then redo the process - the HTTP request and response should appear, and you should be able to see what the sent header values look like)

Comment: The Content-Type is there (as expected is multipart/form-data), but as the response from the server says, there is no boundary. On the call, and from the information @Dmitry posted, the boundary is there as: ------WebKitFormBoundary8NfqfKxFBAK7jMmJ. So I guess I'm missing the boundary definition at the header of the call.